# discord.py creating a bot that sends a specialized preset message in a text channel when specific users join a voice channel

Tags: discord.py

for example when user1 connects to vc1 then "hello user1" is sent in text channel general but when user2 connects to vc1 then "hi user2" is sent in text channel general

im new to coding with discord.py and python in general what would be the easiest way to go about this
below is an example of what i have tried so far

```
@client.event
    async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
      print(member)
      vc = client.get_channel(id=channel id number)
      vc1 = vc.members
      if member in vc1[0] == "User#1234":
        send msg in general text channel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event is well constructed from the point of view, but a little more structure would be good and also some things are completely wrong.

***Have a look at the following code:***

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    channel = before.channel or after.channel

    if channel.id == VoiceChannelID: # Insert voice channel ID
        if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None: # Member joins the defined channel
            channel1 = client.get_channel(GeneralTextChatID) # Define the general channel
            await channel1.send(f"Welcome to the voice channel {member.mention}!") # Mention the member
```

**What did we do?**

- Checked the channel before and after the user joined (`channel=`)
- Checked if the joined channel matches the defined channel
- Sent a message if the channel is correct
- Used an `f-string` to mention the member

Comment: should note that f-strings require python 3.6+

Comment: You are a god, thank you so much! This is exactly what i needed. Have a wonderful day my man.